# jquery find index number of nested li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, event-handling, html-lists

How would i go about getting the index position number of one of the nested LI's? I can get the topnav index's but cannot seem the children index number of the subnav(s).

I would like to create the selector dynamically to target the subnav based on the index of the topnav.

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li><a href="#a">menu item 0</a>
            <ul id="subnav0">
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#a">menu item 1</a>
            <ul id="subnav1">
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery Code

```
 //Event Handler
 function nav_execute(){
    var _index = $('#topnav > li').index(this);//Returns index number of topnav item selected
    var _subnav = '#subnav'+ _index.toString();
    var _selector = _subnav + ' > li'.toString();//the subnav selector
    var _subindex = $(_selector).index();//gets total num of index's
}

//Binded event
$('#topnav > li').bind('click', nav_execute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This code seems to have solved my problem. This checks the parent 'id' and then performs a simple conditional statement to determine which nav was clicked. It then stores the index(s) to their master vars.


 function nav_execute(e){

    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id").toString();

    if(id == "topnav"){
        _index = $(this).index();
        _subindex = null;
    }else{
        _index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
        _subindex = $(this).index();    
    }

    console.log('_index: ' + _index);
    console.log('_subindex: ' + _subindex);

    return false;   
}


$('#topnav > li').live('click', nav_execute);


Thanks for the help from everyone!
```

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that I am really not sure I understood what you are aiming, try replacing your javascript with:

```
$('#topnav  li').bind('click', function (){
  alert($(this).index());   
});
```

See the full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U2kV2/2/)
(this isn't a solution. It is a way to see which elements are firing events and in which order).

Comment: with using the selector above how would track if the item clicked is a topnav item vs. a subnav item?

Answer (score 0):

So I THINK you are trying to say I want to get the 'subNav" ul contained in whatever "#topNav > li" was clicked?

If that is what you are trying to do then this should work

```
//Event Handler
 function nav_execute(){
    var $subNav = $(this).find("ul");

    //I'm not sure what you are trying to do here so im not going to change the functionality
    var subindex = $subNav.index();//gets total num of index's
}

//Binded event
$('#topnav > li').bind('click', nav_execute);
```

**EDIT:**

Per your comment here is a jsfiddle of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/wuFB7/4/

You can just create a selector for those nested li's directly. However since you said they are dynamically generated I changed ".bind" to ".live" since this will allow attaching event handlers to elements created after the initial page load.

Comment: Basically I am just trying to get the index position number of an LI element in a subnav based on a click event. If I click on the third LI in subnav0 I would like to be able to return a the number 2. Reasoning is the menus are created dynamically and it is a basic tracking mechanism.

Comment: That's cool thank you, but is there a way to differentiate between topnav LI and subnav LI clicked? So the alert would give the top LI index number position and subnav LI index number position.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle. I think this is what you want. the alert now shows the subnav index and the index of the li in the topnav.

Comment: Thanks Keith. This is close but I am beginning to think that jquery might be the right tool. I really just want to update variables. If the user clicks on the topnav the topnav var updates and clears the subnav var and per your example if the user clicks the subnav both the variables update. I just can't figure out how to know which they clicked on.